# Python pandas specific header checker

Tags: python, excel, pandas, calculation

I wrote a pandas python code that is taking data from an excel file. This an example code that I am using. But some excel file doesn't have some headers like `Abundance: F1: 127C, Sample` therefore how can I check for the calculation. I am thinking to put try and except cycles but I don't know how to make list after available ones.

thank you very much in advance.

```
# Here I am reading the excel file
Data=pd.read_excel("example.xlsx", header=0)

# Here I am taking the specific headers as list from the excel file
AccessionNum = list(Data['Accession'])
N_127_L = list(Data['Abundance: F1: 127N, Sample'])
C_127_L = list(Data['Abundance: F1: 127C, Sample'])
N_128_L = list(Data['Abundance: F1: 128N, Sample'])

C_128_L = list(Data['Abundance: F1: 128C, Sample'])
N_129_L = list(Data['Abundance: F1: 129N, Sample'])
C_129_L = list(Data['Abundance: F1: 129C, Sample'])

N_130_L = list(Data['Abundance: F1: 130N, Sample'])
C_130_L = list(Data['Abundance: F1: 130C, Sample'])
N_131_L = list(Data['Abundance: F1: 131N, Sample'])

j = 0
for i in AccessionNum:
# Here I am iterating the all of the rows
    N_127 = N_127_L[j]
    C_127 = C_127_L[j]
    N_128 = N_128_L[j]

    C_128 = C_128_L[j]
    N_129 = N_129_L[j]
    C_129 = C_129_L[j]

    N_130 = N_130_L[j]
    C_130 = C_130_L[j]
    N_131 = N_131_L[j]

# Here I am grouping my columns but sometimes one or two doesn't have
    dmsoList = [N_127, C_127, N_128]
    drug1List = [C_128, N_129, C_129]
    drug2List = [N_130, C_130, N_131]

# Here I am doing some calculation which is not important
    dmso = statistics.mean(dmsoList)
    drug1 = statistics.mean(drug1List)
    drug2 = statistics.mean(drug2List)

    log2_drug1 = '=LOG({}/{},2)'.format(drug1, dmso)
    log2_drug2 = '=LOG({}/{},2)'.format(drug2, dmso)

    ttest_drug1 = stats.ttest_ind(dmsoList, drug1List, equal_var=True)
    ttest_drug2 = stats.ttest_ind(dmsoList, drug2List, equal_var=True)
    log10_ttest_drug1 = '=-LOG({})'.format(ttest_drug1[1])
    log10_ttest_drug2 = '=-LOG({})'.format(ttest_drug2[1])

    Data.loc[j, 'Log2 Drug_1'] = log2_drug1
    Data.loc[j, 'Log2 Drug_2'] = log2_drug2
    Data.loc[j, '-log10 Drug_1 t-test'] = log10_ttest_drug1
    Data.loc[j, '-log10 Drug_2 t-test'] = log10_ttest_drug2
    j += 1

# Here I am outputting the data as excel file again
Data.to_excel('_Calculation.xlsx')
```

[Example of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upRHF.png)

Comment: hi first sorry i didn't know panda library. 
but i think your question is hard to understand someone.
Q1, Q2 like exactly show up your question.
delete un neccesaary code and show testable example someone. 
(what header like in file - empty or null , what you want calculate method)
hope it helps

Comment: @HulkChoi Thank you very much Hulk. Now I added example excel file and some explanation on the code. Calculation part is not important and my problem probably is a basic python code problem not pandas. I will be glad if you have any idea.